# feature importance results differ in R and sklearn random forest regression

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm working on a regression problem, and have been using both the [R randomForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package as well as the python [sklearn random forest regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) estimator.

The R package can calculate the feature importance score in two different ways:

> 1. The first measure is computed from permuting OOB data: For each tree, the prediction error on the out-of-bag portion of the data is
>    recorded (error rate for classification, MSE for regression). Then the
>    same is done after permuting each predictor variable. The difference
>    between the two are then averaged over all trees, and normalized by
>    the standard deviation of the differences.
> 2. The second measure is the total decrease in node impurities from splitting on the variable, averaged over all trees. For
>    classification, the node impurity is measured by the Gini index. For
>    regression, it is measured by residual sum of squares (RSS).

Whereas sklearn does it only in the latter way ([see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821880/1153897)).

I've been interested in comparing method #2 in both implementations so I've done the following:

## R

```
iteration_count <- 3
seeds <- seq(1,iteration_count,1)
tree_count <- 500

for(i in 1:iteration_count) {
  set.seed(seeds[[i]])
  rfmodels[[i]]<- randomForest(y ~ .,X,ntree=tree_count,importance=TRUE,na.action=na.omit)
}

# convert all iterations into matrix form
imp_score_matrix <- do.call(cbind, lapply(models_selected, function(x) { importance(x, scale=T, type=1)[,1] }))

# Calculate mean and s.d. for importance ranking of each feature based on a matrix of feature importance scores
imp_score_stats <- (cbind(rowMeans(imp_score_matrix),rowSds(imp_score_matrix)))

# Order the matrix so that the features are ranked by mean (most important features will be in the last rows)
ordered_imp_score_stats <- imp_score_stats[order(imp_score_stats[,1]),]
```

## sklearn

```
# get FIS through mean decrease in impurity (default method for sklearn)
num_iter = 3 # number of times to generate FIS; will average over these scores
trees = 500
seeds = [l for l in range(num_iter)]
FIS = []

# R implementation of RF settings - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf
num_features = 1/3.0 # see mtry
leaf = 5 # see nodesize

FIS_map = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(X.columns.values)} # {feature: i}
for i in range(num_iter):
    print "Iteration", i
    clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs = -1, n_estimators = trees, random_state = seeds[i],
                               max_features = num_features, min_samples_leaf = leaf)
    clf = clf.fit(X,y)
    FIS.append(clf.feature_importances_)

FIS_stats = pd.DataFrame(FIS).describe().T # will have columns mean, std, etc
FIS_stats = FIS_stats.sort("mean", ascending = False) # most important features on top
FIS_stats['OTU'] = FIS_map # add the OTU ID
FIS_stats = FIS_stats.set_index('OTU')
FIS_stats = FIS_stats[FIS_stats['mean'] > 0] # remove those OTU features with no mean importance
```

As you can see, I've tried to adjust the default settings in sklearn to match those used in R.  The problem is, I get different results for each implementation.  Now, I understand that there are various non-deterministic dimensions to random forests, so I don't expect the features to be ranked exactly the same; however, I'm seeing almost no overlap in important features.

Furthermore, when I use the best *X* features, those chosen by R perform much better than those in sklearn on a hold-out sample set.

Am I doing something wrong?  What could explain the resulting difference?

## Update

Per the comment regarding the feature importances being calculated with the Gini index in sklearn, the source code for random forest regression shows that [MSE is used to calculate impurity](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L1013).

So, it looks like R uses RSS and sklearn uses MSE, the [relationship being](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73540/mean-squared-error-and-residual-sum-of-squares):

[image]

Could this account for the difference?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the number of iterantions for both the scripts?

Comment: Does not make a difference :(

Comment: The documentation of the R random forest says: _For classification, the node impurity is measured by the Gini index. For regression, it is measured by residual sum of squares._ As you are doing regression, maybe this is the difference? In the scikit-learn doc only Gini criterion is mentioned to measure impurity.

Comment: I find your R code `randomForest(X ~ .,y,ntree=tree_count, ...)` strange. If your `X` data frame does not include response, you need `randomForest(X, y, ntree=tree_count, ...)` without using the formula.  If `X` does include response, you need formula interface only `randomForest(y ~ ., data=X, ntree=tree_count, ...) ` With your code as it is,  I am not sure, what you are fitting. Could you check this?

Comment: indeed you're right; I had made a mistake when cleaning up the code for posting - I've updated it to reflect the correct way I'm actually calculating FIS