# scikit learn - feature importance calculation in decision trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, feature-selection

I'm trying to understand how feature importance is calculated for decision trees in sci-kit learn. This question has been asked before, but I am unable to reproduce the results the algorithm is providing.

For example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree.export import export_graphviz
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif

X = [[1,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0]]

y = [1,0,1,1]

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)

feat_importance = clf.tree_.compute_feature_importances(normalize=False)
print("feat importance = " + str(feat_importance))

out = StringIO()
out = export_graphviz(clf, out_file='test/tree.dot')
```

results in feature importance:

```
feat importance = [0.25       0.08333333 0.04166667]
```

and gives the following decision tree:

[image: decision tree]

Now, this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92843/194377) to a similar question suggests the importance is calculated as

[image: formula_a]

Where G is the node impurity, in this case the gini impurity. This is the impurity reduction as far as I understood it. However, for feature 1 this should be:

[image: formula_b]

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821880/1618893) suggests the importance is weighted by the probability of reaching the node (which is approximated by the proportion of samples reaching that node). Again, for feature 1 this should be:

[image: formula_c]

Both formulas provide the wrong result. How is the feature importance calculated correctly?

Comment: The importance is also normalised if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L1056-L1092). The normalisation is done in such a way that the sum of the output would be equal to 1. You can also see the other details about computation there.

Comment: Yes, actually my example code was wrong. The calculated feature importance is computed with `clf.tree_.compute_feature_importances(normalize=False)`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think feature importance depends on the implementation so we need to look at the documentation of scikit-learn.

> The feature importances. The higher, the more important the feature. The importance of a feature is computed as the (normalized) total reduction of the criterion brought by that feature. It is also known as the Gini importance

That reduction or weighted information gain is defined as :

> The weighted impurity decrease equation is the following:
>
> `N_t / N * (impurity - N_t_R / N_t * right_impurity
>                       - N_t_L / N_t * left_impurity)`
>
> where N is the total number of samples, N_t is the number of samples at the current node, N_t_L is the number of samples in the left child, and N_t_R is the number of samples in the right child.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier

Since each feature is used once in your case, feature information must be equal to equation above.

For X[2] :

`feature_importance = (4 / 4) * (0.375 - (0.75 * 0.444)) = 0.042`

For X[1] :

`feature_importance = (3 / 4) * (0.444 - (2/3 * 0.5)) = 0.083`

For X[0] :

`feature_importance = (2 / 4) * (0.5) = 0.25`

Comment: Great answer!, just X[2] is X[0], and X[0] is X[2]

Comment: where are you quoting the formula from?

Comment: @Pulse9 I think what you said is untrue. X[2]'s feature importance is 0.042

Comment: @agent18, the formula is located under `min_impurity_decrease` parameter in the given link.

Answer (score 8):

A single feature can be used in the different branches of the tree, feature importance then is it's total contribution in reducing the impurity.

```py
feature_importance += number_of_samples_at_parent_where_feature_is_used\*impurity_at_parent-left_child_samples\*impurity_left-right_child_samples\*impurity_right
```

impurity is the gini/entropy value

```py
normalized_importance = feature_importance/number_of_samples_root_node(total num of samples)
```

In the above eg:

```py
feature_2_importance = 0.375*4-0.444*3-0*1 = 0.16799 , 
normalized = 0.16799/4(total_num_of_samples) = 0.04199
```

If `feature_2` was used in other branches calculate the it's importance at each such parent node & sum up the values.

There is a difference in the feature importance calculated & the ones returned by the library as we are using the truncated values seen in the graph.

Instead, we can access all the required data using the 'tree_' attribute of the classifier which can be used to probe the features used, threshold value, impurity, no of samples at each node etc..

eg: `clf.tree_.feature` gives the list of features used. A negative value indicates it's a leaf node.

Similarly `clf.tree_.children_left/right` gives the index to the `clf.tree_.feature` for left & right children

Using the above traverse the tree & use the same indices in `clf.tree_.impurity & clf.tree_.weighted_n_node_samples` to get the gini/entropy value and number of samples at the each node & at it's children.

```py
def dt_feature_importance(model,normalize=True):

    left_c = model.tree_.children_left
    right_c = model.tree_.children_right

    impurity = model.tree_.impurity    
    node_samples = model.tree_.weighted_n_node_samples 

    # Initialize the feature importance, those not used remain zero
    feature_importance = np.zeros((model.tree_.n_features,))

    for idx,node in enumerate(model.tree_.feature):
        if node >= 0:
            # Accumulate the feature importance over all the nodes where it's used
            feature_importance[node]+=impurity[idx]*node_samples[idx]- \
                                   impurity[left_c[idx]]*node_samples[left_c[idx]]-\
                                   impurity[right_c[idx]]*node_samples[right_c[idx]]

    # Number of samples at the root node
    feature_importance/=node_samples[0]

    if normalize:
        normalizer = feature_importance.sum()
        if normalizer > 0:
            feature_importance/=normalizer

    return feature_importance
```

This function will return the exact same values as returned by `clf.tree_.compute_feature_importances(normalize=...)`

To sort the features based on their importance

```py
features = clf.tree_.feature[clf.tree_.feature>=0] # Feature number should not be negative, indicates a leaf node
sorted(zip(features,dt_feature_importance(clf,False)[features]),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
```