# How to " real calculate " random forest feature importance on sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I follow this issue to calculate feature importance on decision tree: 
[scikit learn - feature importance calculation in decision trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170296/scikit-learn-feature-importance-calculation-in-decision-trees)

However, I can't get correct value on calculating feature importance on random forest.
For example:
I use code like this and get random forest trees. I use sklearn package on python.

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2, max_features='log2')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
feature_imp = pd.Series(clf.feature_importances_, index = features_id).sort_values(ascending=False)
feature_imp_each_tree = [tree.feature_importances_.T for tree in clf.estimators_]
```

[image] 
[image]

And then, I know feature importance `#1: 0.1875, #2: 0.3313, #3: 0.4813`

feature importance on each tree is

**left tree** `#1: 0.375, #2: 05625, #3: 0.0625`
**right tree** `#1: 0, #2: 0.1, #3: 0.9`

Therefore I follow step to calculate ...

`feature #1 on left tree: (2/4)*(0.5-0-0)=0.25
feature #2 on left tree: (2/4)*(0.38-0-0)=0.38
feature #3 on left tree: (4/4)*(0.44-0.38*2/4-0.5*2/4)=0`

`feature #1 on right tree: 0
feature #2 on right tree: (5/5)*(0.28-0.38*3/5-0)=0.052
feature #3 on right tree: (3/5)*(0.38-0-0)=0.228`

I know importance on random forest need to normalize to sum = 1
therefore after normalize (importance/sum)

`sum = 0.25+0.38+0 = 0.44
feature #1 on left tree: 0.25/0.44 = 0.5682
feature #2 on left tree: 0.19/0.44 = 0.4318
feature #3 on left tree: 0/0.44 = 0`

`sum = 0+0.052+0.228 = 0.28
feature #1 on right tree: 0/0.28 = 0
feature #2 on right tree: 0.052/0.28 = 0.186
feature #3 on right tree: 0.228/0.28 = 0.814`

and then calculate average:

`feature #1: (0.5682+0)/2 = 0.2841
feature #2: (0.4318+0.186)/2 = 0.3088
feature #3: (0+0.814)/2 = 0.4071`

Although sorting is correct but value isn't correct, please help me how to calculate that thanks