# Statistical significance of important features in a random forest?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a random forest classifier which gave me a feature importance rank.

How can I derive statistical significance of the important features, similar to a regression model where you can infer statistical significance of the betas?

Comment: Do you want to use a parametric or non-parametric test ? e.g. t-test or permutation testing?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit too broad and unclear.

An easy way you can look at the `feature_importance_`values **as percentage is by normalizing their values**:

```
importance_sum = sum(clf. feature_importances_)
feature_importance_as_percent =  [100*(x/sum) for x in clf.feature_importances_]
```

Other methods would involve parametric or non-parametric tests.

Read also this: [How are feature_importances in RandomForestClassifier determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15810339/5025009)